# Why does Coverage.py ignore files with no coverage?

Tags: python, coverage.py

I first run

```
nosetests --with-coverage
```

So I should have a .coverage file with all the default settings.

Within folder_1, I have file_1.py, file_2.py, and file_3.py

When I cd into folder_1 and run

```
coverage report
```

It outputs:

[image]

It doesn't generate anything for file_3.py! But then when I run:

```
coverage report file_3.py
```

it says:

[image]

Does it skip files with no coverage in the report? How can I change it so the report shows me the results of every *.py file?

Comment: Please copy & paste the output from `coverage` instead of posting images of text.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to specify a source directory for coverage.py to find files that have never been executed at all.  You can use `--source=folder_1` on the command line, or `[run] source=folder_1` in your .coveragerc file.

Comment: Somehow, when I execute: "coverage report", I get the full report. But when I execute: "coverage run", it says "Nothing to do." What am I doing wrong here? 
I'm looking at these docs: http://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/coverage-4.3.4/source.html

Comment: "coverage run" needs a program to run:  "coverage run myprog.py"

Comment: So for the files that have never been executed, is it possible for me to just specify the location and say 'run every thing here', rather than name every individual file?

Comment: You are confusing the running of code with the analysis of code. You have to tell coverage what to run. Once it has run that file, the `--source=folder_1` options tells it to consider all of the Python files in folder_1 when looking for code that hasn't been executed.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same scenario yesterday and lost some time trying make Coverage consider the corresponding to this `file_3.py`. Ned Batchelder's answer is completely correct and helped me but when handling multiple `folder_1` folders in the same level in the hierarchy I'd have to set all of them as source and that is not ideal.

The key is this part of the [official doc](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/6.5.0/source.html):

> If the source option is specified, only code in those locations will be measured. Specifying the source option also enables coverage.py to report on unexecuted files, since it can search the source tree for files that haven’t been measured at all. Only importable files (ones at the root of the tree, or in directories with a `__init__.py` file) will be considered.

So unexecuted files will only be analysed **if you point at them**. For this scenario that means two options:

1. Set your folder directly as source directory running the tests with the flag `--source=folder_1` (which is covered on Neds' answer).
2. If this is a subfolder of a bigger project you can also just set the source folder as the main project folder but then you need to set the directories you want analysed as packages, creating an `__init__.py` file in them.

For instance if you have:

```
src/
 folder_1/
   __init__.py
   file_1.py
   file_2.py
   file_3.py
```

You can just run with the flag `--source=src` and `folder_1` files will be discoverable as well.

Hope that helps someone in the future.